# Citation error with natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm creating a secondary file in a project where I need to refer to citations from the bibtex file, but I'm getting an error. I have a file called references.bib and a file called notes.tex where I need to reference the citations. I have the following code at the top of my notes.tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Notes}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Reference 1: \cite{author1}

\end{document}
```

I obtain the following error when I compile: "Package natbib warning: Citation undefined"

I've tried compiling pdf, then bibtex, then pdf, then pdf again according to the two posts that I saw on this site documenting similar errors, but that did not work.

What should I do? Is this specific to the fact that I'm not in the main.tex file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Why are you loading both the `natbib` and the `chicago` citation management packages. Load one or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of the {chicago} citation package but I still get the same error. What do you recommend?

Comment: It also doesn't make a lot of sense to load both `\usepackage{cite}` and `\usepackage{natbib}`. For the most part, `natbib` has more features than `cite`, so you should probably also drop `\usepackage{cite}`.

Comment: Sorry, I only noticed just now that you weren't loading just two citation management packages, but in fact *three* -- `cite`, `natbib`, *and* `chicago`. The `cite` and `natbib` packages are also mutually incompatible. Thus, let me amend my previous recommendation to "load *only one* of `cite`, `natbib`, and `chicago`."

Comment: The code you've shown so far does not have a `\bibliography{<bib file name without extension>}` and `\bibliographystyle{<style name>}` call. You need both of these, otherwise BibTeX won't know which entries to take and how to format them.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked.

Comment: One quick follow up question: I don't really want a references section in this file since I have one in the main.tex file. Is there any way to make it hidden, even though I need to include \bibliography{} and \bibliographystyle{} in order for the code to work?

Comment: How are you including this file in the main file, or combining them? What should hyperref do about linking the citations if their targets aren't in the document?

Comment: So I ended up getting rid of hyperref anyway. I have this as a second file in the project, separate from main.tex

Comment: Hmm. This is an odd one. Maybe put the bibliography inside a savebox that you never use? `\bibliographystyle{<style>}\newsavebox{\mybib}\savebox{\mybib}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{<bibfile>}}}`. You're using author-date style? With numbers, they might not match the main document.